# Android Set ImageView image src in Style

Tags: android, coding-style, imageview

I need to set the ImageView's src within my style, but I cant find a good example of anyone doing this and when I try the below code, it crashes the app.

```
<ImageView android:src="@style/TitleBarImage"></ImageView>

<style name="TitleBarImage">     
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>     
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>     
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/whiteButton</item> 
</style>
```

This should be simple.  What gives?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your xml is incorrect:

```
<ImageView style="@style/TitleBarImage" />
```

And styles.xml :

```
<style name="TitleBarImage">     
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>     
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>     
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/whiteButton</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: <ImageView style is what I needed to know...I kept trying things like <ImageView android:style, <ImageView android:theme etc  Thanks!