# Can you get LayoutPrams from an Android Style?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

Can you get LayoutPrams from an Android Style? If so, how do I do it? - API lvl 8

(I'm trying to apply styling to dynamically created elements - if there's a better way to do this I'm all ears)

---

I've tried the `LayoutInflater` way (where you make individual .xml files then call them as a template and cast them - where the .xml element has `android:style="..."` in it - this seems like a lot of unnecessary work; and ultimately didn't work for me.

### Sample Code (using LayoutInflater) [not working/styling]

```
public void build_gui() {

    // can load 'template' layout elements
    LayoutInflater layout_Inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    // the master_layout - this is the bottom layer
    LinearLayout m_ll = (LinearLayout) layout_Inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.main_master_linearlayout, null);
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) layout_Inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.main_master_linearlayout, null);

    for (Feed_element fe : mApp.feed_elements) {
        Log.d(tag, "GUI: " + fe.title);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) layout_Inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.main_element_container_relativelayout, null);

        // init - preview image
        ImageView iv_preview = (ImageView) layout_Inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.main_element_preview_imageview, null);
        // init - title
        TextView tv_title = (TextView) layout_Inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.main_element_title_textview, null);
        // init - desc
        TextView tv_desc = (TextView) layout_Inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.main_element_desc_textview, null);

        // set the preview bitmap to teh default of no preview
        Bitmap preview = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.no_preview);

        if (fe.preview != "") {
            Log.d(tag, "Downloading IMG: " + fe.preview);
            // if there was a preview get the image
            preview = mApp.web.downloadFile(fe.preview);
        }

        // get the pxl aprox
        int pxl = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (float) PREVIEW_SIZE, this
                        .getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        iv_preview.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(preview, pxl,
                pxl, true));

        if (fe.title != "" || fe.title != null) {
            tv_title.setText(fe.title);
        }

        if (fe.description != "" || fe.description != null) {
            tv_title.setText(fe.description);
        }

        // THIS is the type of hard coding my styles that i would like to avoid
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams base_layout_pram = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams iv_preview_prams = base_layout_pram;
        iv_preview_prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        iv_preview_prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tv_title_prams = base_layout_pram;
        tv_title_prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, iv_preview.getId());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tv_desc_prams = base_layout_pram;
        tv_desc_prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, iv_preview.getId());
        tv_desc_prams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv_title.getId());

        rl.addView(iv_preview);
        rl.addView(tv_title, tv_title_prams);
        rl.addView(tv_desc, tv_desc_prams);

        ll.addView(rl);
        mApp.feed_id_count++;
    }

    sv.addView(ll);
    m_ll.addView(sv);
    setContentView(m_ll);
}
```

In the code above I understand I have to set all the `RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF`'s and such... but i'm trying to avoid the following:

```
    // THIS is the type of hard coding my styles that i would like to avoid
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams base_layout_pram = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

### Example template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    style="@style/main_element_preview_imageView">

</ImageView>
```

### Style Example

```
<style name="main_element_preview_imageView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">75dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">75dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitStart</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
</style>
```

### Thoughts

I believe it would be possible to create my own overloaded class with these properties set to default - but again, this seems counter productive to the idea of having an element style.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in your style you have to declare the parent of the style, i.e.

```
> <style name="main_element_preview_imageView" parent="Widget.ImageView">
```

Comment: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.ImageView'
It seems as if this is unnecessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598527/android-set-imageview-image-src-in-style

Comment: Do you have the style referenced correctly in your xml files. If you do, then it can only be one of two things:
Too low API Level or
No Support

Comment: I am using API lvl 8 (I added it to the question for clarification) In the style documentation it only mentions an API level in reference to 
themes based on platform versions (I added an example 'template')