# Is it possible to setup background in style for all ImageView in application

Tags: android

I know i could create some style and set it like this.

```
<ImageView
        style="@style/MyCustomStyle" />
```

But I couldn't find an opportunity to setup it directly for whole application as default style for example like TextView.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/CustomTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

Also I can't find parent ImageView wiget style.

```
<style name="MyCustomStyle" parent="android:Widget.???"/>
```

Is it possible with ImageView.

Comment: Did you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598527/android-set-imageview-image-src-in-style

Comment: @emandt Did you read the question?;) Look 1st chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would rather create a custom ImageView and add style to it. Then use the CustomImageView and it'll have the same style through out the app

Comment: Actually this is not a solution for my question. I know there is a lot of workarounds but I wonder is there a way to do it in right way.

Comment: There is no direct way to do this.

Comment: Hm... this is weird. I thought I missed something.